# Stuck in definite integral of a function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\tan (x)}{\tan(x)+\sec(x)}dx $$
I was given this problem now using property of definate integral i then equated this expression to $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi-x\tan (x)}{\tan(x)+\sec(x)}dx $$ and $$2I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi\tan (x)}{\tan(x)+\sec(x)}dx=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{sin (x)}{sin(x)+1}dx$$ now what am i supposed to do help i am stuck

Comment: On that last integral, you can add and subtract 1 in the numerator, than split the fraction. You will get to integrate 1 and -1/(sinx+1) On this integral, multiply top and bottom with 1-sinx and apply pythagorean theorem on the denom. It should then be easy...Try it

Comment: ok let me try out :D

Comment: The anti derivative of 1 is x and the anti derivative of the second integral is (1-sinx)/cosx. I have the answer but will wait for a moment...

Comment: is it $\frac{\pi^2-2}{2}$ ??

Comment: You need to add a pi behind the 2 in the numerator (distribute the pi in front of your integral)

Comment: ouch my mistake , yes got the answer can you help me out in Continuity question

Comment: In the given integral, multiply through by cosx. You will then get a function that is continuous on the given interval.

Comment: @Tesla : Why is your original integral $I$ equal to the second displayed one?

Comment: @Stefan because $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f({a+b}-x)dx$ definite integral property

Comment: @Tesla : Thanks.  Your second integral is missing parentheses in the numerator of the integrand, but I know what you mean now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want 
$$\int \frac{\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}\,dx,$$ 
one  possible approach is to multiply top and bottom by $\sec x-\tan x$. Since $\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x=1$, our integral becomes 
$$\int (\sec x\tan x -\tan^2 x)\,dx,$$
that is
$$\int (\sec x\tan x-\sec^2 x+1)\,dx.$$
Each part is now familiar.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's actually pretty cool too! I actually multplied the given integral by cosx straight from the beginning, also became straight forward.

Comment: There are many ways. Actually OP had already done the nice part. (I think of the nice part as the taking advantage of the partial symmetry.) The part that was left for me to do has a more mechanical character.

Comment: better method i'd say because it makes things fairly simple enough

Comment: The Maple commands $$with(Student[Calculus1]):$$
$$IntTutor(Pi*tan(x)/(sec(x)+tan(x)), x = 0 .. (1/2)*Pi);
 $$ show the solution step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Call the integral I. Let $x\rightarrow(\pi-x)$ and symmetry to get $$I=\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x dx}{\sin x +1}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin x}.$$ Next, let $x\rightarrow(\pi/2-x)$ to get $$ I=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d}{dt}\tan(t/2) dt=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi$$